# SQLite Analyze (sqlite_stat4). System.Data.SQLite vs Microsoft.Data.Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, system.data.sqlite, microsoft.data.sqlite

I am trying to execute `ANALYZE` command for Sqlite.
But it works only for `System.Data.SQLite`.
It does not work for `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` version, **no errors, no exceptions**, just nothing happens.

When you execute ANALYZE - new system table will be created `sqlite_stat4`.
It helps SQLite to optimize the query plan.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html

**How to make it work for EntityFramework/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite ?**

```
    // .NET 6
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemDataSQLite();
            MicrosoftDataSqlite();

            Console.WriteLine("End...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        
        private static void SystemDataSQLite()
        {
            // System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.118
            string connectionString = PrepareNewDbConnectionString("SystemDataSQLite.db");
            using SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "ANALYZE";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private static void MicrosoftDataSqlite()
        {
            // Microsoft.Data.Sqlite version 6.0.25
            string connectionString = PrepareNewDbConnectionString("MicrosoftDataSqlite.db");
            using SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "ANALYZE";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        
        private static string PrepareNewDbConnectionString(string dbFile)
        {
            string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDir + "db");
            string filePath = dir.FullName + "\\" + dbFile;
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }

            return $@"Data Source={filePath};";
        }
    }
```

I create example with System.Data.SQLite and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`sqlite_stat4` table](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#stat4tab) is only created by `ANALYZE` and used by the query planner if the version of sqlite being used was compiled with the [`SQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4`](https://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_stat4) option defined. It defaults to not being enabled.

The two C# libraries you're testing likely include two different versions of sqlite built with different options.

You should still be seeing a [`sqlite_stat1` table](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#the_sqlite_stat1_table) after running `ANALYZE` with both; it just has less detailed statistics about table contents than you get with stat4.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see stat1 table. I used command PRAGMA compile_options; in both output DB files (System and Microsoft). I see that ENABLE_STAT4 is enabled and both lists are identical. Even if I make connection using 'System' to DB which was made by 'Microsoft' and execute ANALYZE - stat4 table will be created.

It is interesting, if I execute "ANALYZE blabla" using 'Microsoft', I will get error "blabla table does not exist".

Comment: *used command PRAGMA compile_options; in both output DB files* The database doesn't matter, the version of the sqlite library does. Are you checking the options in C# programs using the two different libraries, or in some other tool (where the options will be whatever *that* tool's version of sqlite was built with)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was using DB Browser for SQLite Version 3.12.2.
Now I tested this command using each library to see the list. Microsoft lib does not have ENABLE_STAT4 option (((( Thank you for the help.